# Validating ActiveRecord attribute length deppending on other Object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to create a validation that enforce the `:phone` field to be 9 digit long if the current object has `country_code`  set to `ES`.

Im trying to do something like this but it doesn't work.

```
validates_length_of :phone, :is => 9, :message => "number needs to be at least 9 digits." if self.country_code == "ES"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
validates_length_of :phone, :is => 9,
:message => "number needs to be at least 9 digits.",
:if => "country_code == 'ES'"
```

Or

```
validates_length_of :phone, :is => 9,
:message => "number needs to be at least 9 digits.",
:if => Proc.new { |a| a.country_code == 'ES' }
```

Take a look at the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation).